# jQuery buttons selector wait ajax finished php exec command using async-await not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, loops, async-await, jquery-selectors

I have a php page with multiple forms that are sending an exec command to the server:

Form 0, button RunAll -> It must run all the following button commands sequentially with jQuery class selector loop

Form 1, button 1 -> Exec Apache shell cmd 1

Form 2, button 2 -> Exec Apache shell cmd 2

Form3, button 3 -> Exec Apache shell cmd 3

I want that RunAll button runs all the requests in ajax async = true to do not freeze the page but sequentially one after the other.
The issue is that the jQuery loop clicks all the buttons together and I am not able to wait (using async-await) that the first ajax call is finished before it clicks the second button and then so on for the third button.

Please help me.

I have tried 
1- global variable in in ajax success:
2- Promises
3- Async-await

The Apache runs out of memory because of all processes are running at the same time

```
 function submitMultiForm(){
$('.btn-info').each(function() {
    asyncClick($(this));
});
 }



async function asyncClick(myBttObj)
{
    //GET THE SPECIFIC FORM AND TEXT AREA
    var myForm = myBttObj.parent();//alert(myForm.attr('id'));
    var myFormAreaText = myBttObj.siblings('.myanswer');//alert(myFormAreaText.attr('id'));
    //SET icons
    var mySpinIcon = myBttObj.siblings('.fa-spin');
    var mySuccIcon = myBttObj.siblings('.fa-check');
    var myErrIcon = myBttObj.siblings('.fa-times');
    var myErrAjxIcon = myBttObj.siblings('.fa-exclamation-triangle');

    var url = myForm.attr("action");
    var serializedData = myForm.serialize()+'&'+$('#fparam').serialize();

    try {

        const res = await doAjax(url, serializedData, mySpinIcon, mySuccIcon, myErrIcon,myErrAjxIcon);

            //write always the log
            var myAreaID = myFormAreaText.attr('id');
            //var filtered_data = res.html();
            myFormAreaText.append( res );   //I added exit to the if isset($_POST) to not giving back the whole page
            //(because the url is the same page of the origin of the ajax request)
            //brwsr console
            console.log(myAreaID)+':';
            console.log(res);

            //blur off button
            myBttObj.blur();

    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}


  function doAjax(url, serializedData, mySpinIcon, mySuccIcon, myErrIcon,myErrAjxIcon)
  {
      let result;

      try {
            result = $.ajax({ url:url,
                                  type:"post",
                                  data: serializedData,
                                  datatype: 'html',
                                  beforeSend: function() {mySpinIcon.show();mySuccIcon.hide();myErrIcon.hide();myErrAjxIcon.hide()},
                                  success: function(data) {
                                      if ( data.toLowerCase().indexOf("error") >-1 ) {
                                          mySpinIcon.hide();mySuccIcon.hide();myErrIcon.show();myErrAjxIcon.hide();//error from the shell
                                      } else {
                                          mySpinIcon.hide();mySuccIcon.show();myErrIcon.hide();myErrAjxIcon.hide();
                                      }
                                  },
                                  error: function() {mySpinIcon.hide();mySuccIcon.hide();myErrIcon.hide();myErrAjxIcon.show()}
                              });
          return result;
      } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
      }
  }
```

Comment: If you run async don't expect to be sequentially one after the other, because they run async. Guess you need the calls to be sync, so when one returns, the next is called.

Comment: if I use a simpler code with only an ajax call with async=false it is working but not as expected because the Apache CMD1 is taking at least 16 sec. to complete and the HTML page is freezed. I don't want that: I would like that by pressing the button 'Run all' all the btns of all the below forms are clicked and the ajax CMD1,2,3 are stacked in a row one after the other.

Answer (score 0):

Your attempted solution seems to be based on a misunderstanding of how the `await` keyword pauses the execution of an `async` function. The key insight here is that only the execution of your `async` function is paused, not the execution of the rest of your script, such as the function calling the `async` functions. See [MDN on await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) for a good explanation, in particular this paragraph (*emphasis mine*):

> An await can split execution flow, **allowing the caller of the await's function to resume execution** before the deferred continuation of the await's function. After the await defers the continuation of its function, if this is the first await executed by the function, immediate execution also continues by **returning to the function's caller** a pending Promise for the completion of the await's function **and resuming execution of that caller**.

Note that you are calling your async functions synchronously in your event handler for `.btn-info`, resulting in the following execution order:

- `asyncClick` runs for the first button ("A1"), its execution is suspended while it *awaits* `doAjax` ("D1") to yield a result
- `asyncClick` runs for the second button ("A2"), its execution is suspended while it *awaits* `doAjax` ("D2") to yield a result
- (other `asyncClick` calls are executed as above)
- *(some time passes)*
- when D1 yields, A1 continues execution
- and so on...

This is what causes your server to start processing everything concurrently.

Instead, you need to explicitly add logic that only triggers the next async call when the previous one has returned. There are many ways to do this, with `async/await` as well as plain Promise objects.

Additional notes:

- If you litter your code with some `console.log()` statements, you will be able to inspect the order in which your functions are executed. (Your logging points of interest would be when functions are entered, and when execution continues after an `await` statement.)
- the keyword you seem to be looking for is *serialization* (to describe waiting for the completion of a command before the next), you should be able to find good resources if you add this term to your searches.

---

On a higher level note, this sentence:

> The Apache runs out of memory because of all processes are running at the same time

suggests that you might have an architectural problem, since there is actually no *semantical* need to run these commands serialized, it's only an implementation- or hardware-based limitation that forces you to do this. (ie. it is not that CMD2 does not make sense until CMD1 was run, it's just that your server is unable to run both at the same time due to low memory.)

Ideally, your application frontend would not need to know about these issues at all, it should just be able to wait until the server returns for each command -- whether the server is able to work on these commands concurrently or not, is up to the discretion of the server.

However, these higher level questions about code organization would be better suited for other sites of the network, such as [softwareengineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) or [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).